# CodeIgniter 3 - Dynamically Load Client Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection, codeigniter-3

I have a main database, lets call it `admin_db`. This database stores all info about my existing clients and the database to use when they login into my system. My login page have 3 fields:-

- `Company ID`
- `Username`
- `Password`

So the intended flow is that when a user enter all the 3 fields, the main database will be queried for the value of `Company ID` which then returns the name of the user's database, eg. `client_x_db` and then authenticate the `Username` and `Password` in that client database. If user is authenticated, from that point onwards, the client database `client_x_db` will be used.

I know that I can load the main admin database, `admin_db` as the default database in config/database.php but how can I dynamically load the client's database to authenticate the user credentials FIRST before using it permanently once user have been authenticated. Please note that until user is AUTHENTICATED, the main database `admin_db` is still being used.

I hope I have made my flow description clear and look forward to any tips from the experts here. Thanks.

Below is my current setup.

In config/database.php.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'admin_user',
    'password' => 'admin_password',
    'database' => 'admin_db',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8mb4',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['client-x'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'client_user',
    'password' => 'client_password',
    'database' => 'client_x_db',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8mb4',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

In my authentication class, I query the main database, retrieve the client database info and load it as follows.

```
$clientDb = $this->admin_model->get_client_database_info($company_id);
// Note: $clientDb has value of client-x

$db1 = $this->load->database($clientDb, TRUE);
// Similar to $db1 = $this->load->database('client-x', TRUE); 

$is_authenticated = $db1->query(AUTHENTHICATE USER CREDENTIAL);

// If authenticated, then use $db1 from this point onwards.

// If failed authentication, then drop $db1 database connection and return error message.
```

So my question is whether there is a simpler and elegant way without having to pre-populate all my client's database connection in config/database.php but to dynamically load the client database based on what is stored in the main database `admin_db`.

Comment: doesn't this help? https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html#connecting-to-multiple-databases

Comment: @delboy1978uk: Don't that mean that I have to define the client's database config first in config/database.php? Then load that database using that code? Is there a way to dynamically load the client database config? Thanks.

Comment: i guess your main db could store connection info?

Comment: The main db will store the client's db name and db credentials. But during that brief moment while the user's credentials are being authenthicated, both databases must be loaded. If authenticated, the main db will be disconnected and the client db will be the primary database connection. If authentication fails, then the client db will be disconnnected and the main db will still be the main database connection.

Comment: you got any logic you'd like to share? like your auth code?

Comment: I used both Ion Auth 3 and HybridAuth for athenticating users. User tables are stored in each client's database which is why I need a 2 step process, ie. #1 is to query the main database first to get the client database name and #2 is to authenticate the user based on user tables in the selected client database.

Comment: During my development phase, I did have 1 default database config plus 3 clients database config in config/database.php but as my client base will grow, it will become klunky and unmanageable,... which is why I am looking for a solution to dynamically load the client's database. I have no problems with the authentication part, just this database part.

Comment: I'm afraid i wont be able to really help without seeing some code

Comment: @delboy1978uk: Please see my amended post above that summarize what I have currently. Thanks.